# MPMusicPlayerController: Detect if back or forward skip button is pressed

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmusicplayercontroller

I was wondering if it were possible to detect whether the user presses the back or forward skip button in control center. `MPMusicPlayerControllerNowPlayingItemDidChangeNotification` detects if it is changed, but not if it was back or forwards.

Answer (score 0):

Use indexOfNowPlayingItem property. Save previous index value for items you play and compare it with current index. Next is +1, previous is -1.